# Zend Studio for Eclipse: Useful Features

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio

There are several 'best Eclipse features' topics, with some great information, but there's much that isn't applicable to Zend Studio.

**So, Zend Studio users, what are your best timesavers?**

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few I use:

ctrl-shift-r: open any file in your workspace

ctrl-F8: tab between perspectives

ctrl-click on variable, class or method: of course, jump to applicable definition

Describing a variable so intellisense knows what it is:

```
$variable = someFunction(); /* @var $variable Zend_Form_Element */
```

Answer (score 0):

ctrl-3 gives you a searchable list of all the commands and such available.

ctrl-f6 cycles between open editors

ctrl-shift-t allows you to search for objects

alt-shift-r allows you to rename all the variables with the same name in a given scope